# setState doesnt seem to update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

```
onSelectedRow(user, clickEvent){
     const state = this.state;
    this.state['userId'] = clickEvent.target.getAttribute(user['mta:UserId']);
    this.setState(state);
    console.log(user['mta:UserId']);
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

Okay, so when I click a ***table-cell*** in my app this function gets called.

The point of it is to take the users UserId and set the state. This UserId is later on ***passed down to a child component*** and used to get specific information. The problem is that I get the correct data in the first console.log but when I then log this.

***state the userId is still null for some reason. Anyone had similiar problems?***

Comment: setState is an async operation, it doesn't immediately update the state of your component

Comment: Have you considered [*reading the documentation*](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) ? *"`setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall."*

Comment: You should not be mutating the state like above:
`const state = this.state;
    this.state['userId'] = clickEvent.target.getAttribute(user['mta:UserId']);`

Read here: https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most probably because you're not updating the `const state`, but instead trying to mutate the state itself.
Also, you don't have to make a copy of a state. You can update just the field you want to update like this:

```
onSelectedRow(user, clickEvent) {
    this.setState({
        userId: clickEvent.target.getAttribute(user['mta:UserId'])
    }, () => { console.log(this.state.userId) });
    console.log(user['mta:UserId']);
}
```

Also, your console.log won't read immediate change in the state as `setState` is an async action.

If you really want to read it you can pass the callback to the `setState` which fill fire right after the state is updated, or use React's lifecycle method `componentDidUpdate()`.

Comment: Why the downvotes? That's the correct answer.

Comment: That's what I've written in the answer, so I don't really get what's the problem here. I know React, I pretty much use it everyday.

Comment: Alright, that's more of an answer. I just wanted to correct novafluff's code to make it work, not to make a point about the console.log. I'll update it though.

Comment: @Icepickle, I've updated an answer so it's more informative.

Comment: Yeah it is, but I would remove the first paragraph after the code, the added one is quite clear :)